# Prefix finder c

Tags: c

I am writing a code that finds the number of occurrences of a number of prefixes given in the command line (argv values) in a given string. I need to find the number of times each prefix occurred at the beginning of the word in the string (case insenstive). For example, prefixes are hi, li, al and the string is "I live in a higher building than Alex Highburn.". I need to have hi=2, li=1, al=1.

i am new to C and have tried to write for loops and used strcasecmp but with no luck. can anyone give a suggestion?
I have tried things like this but dont know what to do next:

```
for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
    for(j; j<strlen(argv[i]; j++){
        if strcasecmp(
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: i have tried multiple things along the line of 

for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
    for(j; j<strlen(argv[i]; j++){
          if strcasecmp(

but tbh i dont understand what to do next

Comment: Post the code by editing the question. Do not paste in comment section

Comment: like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WYk3sJTbBpNgRxsc)